# Angular Universal 9 breaks Bootstrap CSS directives

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, angular-universal

I have a running application which is totally fine when I do `npm run start`.
But when I do `npm run build:ssr` and `npm run serve:ssr`, it does not work properly. Strangely, it does not give any error.

When I do `npm run start` I see a button which currently its opacity is 65%. When I hover the mouse, I want the opacity to be 100%.
[image]
[image]

When I do Angular SSR build (`npm run build:ssr` and `npm run serve:ssr`), it does not show the opacity properly.

[image]
[image]

Currently I am using a CDN to load Bootstrap in the app by embedding the link into index.html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.domain.com/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

I have tested and am able to download the CSS file without any problem.

I am adding my angular.json and package.json files here:

angular.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
      "my-app": {
        "root": "",
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "projectType": "application",
        "architect": {
          "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
            "options": {
              "aot": true,
              "outputPath": "dist",
              "index": "src/index.html",
              "main": "src/main.browser.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "assets": [
                "src/assets",
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/robots.txt",
                "src/manifest.json"
              ],
              "styles": [
                "./node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.carousel.min.css",
                "./node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.theme.default.min.css",
                "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              ],
              "scripts": []
            },
            "configurations": {
              "dev": {
                "budgets": [
                  {
                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                    "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                  }
                ],
                "fileReplacements": [
                  {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/browser/environment.ts"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "production": {
                "budgets": [
                  {
                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                    "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                  }
                ],
                "optimization": true,
                "outputHashing": "all",
                "sourceMap": false,
                "statsJson": true,
                "extractCss": true,
                "namedChunks": false,
                "aot": true,
                "extractLicenses": true,
                "vendorChunk": false,
                "buildOptimizer": true,
                "fileReplacements": [
                  {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/browser/environment.prod.ts"
                  }
                ],
                "serviceWorker": true
              }
            }
          },
          "serve": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
            },
            "configurations": {
              "dev": {
                "browserTarget": "my-app:build:dev"
              },
              "production": {
                "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
              }
            }
          },
          "extract-i18n": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
            }
          },
          "test": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
            "options": {
              "main": "src/test.ts",
              "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "scripts": [],
              "styles": [],
              "assets": [
                "src/assets",
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/robots.txt",
                "src/manifest.json"
              ]
            }
          },
          "lint": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
            "options": {
              "tsConfig": [
                "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
              ],
              "exclude": [
                "**/node_modules/**"
              ]
            }
          },
          "server": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
            "options": {
              "outputPath": "dist-server",
              "main": "server.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
              "externalDependencies": [
                "@firebase/firestore"
              ]
            },
            "configurations": {
              "dev": {
                "fileReplacements": [
                  {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/server/environment.ts"
                  }
                ],
                "optimization": true
              },
              "production": {
                "optimization": true,
                "outputHashing": "none",
                "sourceMap": false,
                "namedChunks": false,
                "extractLicenses": true,
                "vendorChunk": false,
                "fileReplacements": [
                  {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/server/environment.prod.ts"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "serve-ssr": {
            "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build",
              "serverTarget": "my-app:server"
            },
            "configurations": {
              "production": {
                "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production",
                "serverTarget": "my-app:server:production"
              },
              "dev": {
                "browserTarget": "my-app:build:dev",
                "serverTarget": "my-app:server:dev"
              }
            }
          },
          "prerender": {
            "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "my-app:server:production",
              "routes": [
                "/"
              ]
            },
            "configurations": {
              "production": {}
            }
          },
          "deploy": {
            "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
            "options": {
              "ssr": true
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "my-app-e2e": {
        "root": "",
        "sourceRoot": "",
        "projectType": "application",
        "architect": {
          "e2e": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
            "options": {
              "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
              "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve"
            }
          },
          "lint": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
            "options": {
              "tsConfig": [
                "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
              ],
              "exclude": [
                "**/node_modules/**"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "defaultProject": "my-app",
    "schematics": {
      "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "prefix": "app",
        "styleext": "scss"
      },
      "@schematics/angular:directive": {
        "prefix": "app"
      }
    },
    "cli": {
      "analytics": "64925903-0f96-433a-83be-7a3fb8485063"
    }
  }
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "9.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "ng serve",
      "ssr": "ng run my-app:serve-ssr ",
      "ssr:watch": "ng run my-app:serve-ssr:dev",
      "format:check": "prettier --write --config ./.prettierrc --list-different \"src/{app,environments,styles}/**/*{.ts,.json,.scss}\"",
      "build": "ng build",
      "build:server": "ng run my-app:server:production",
      "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
      "build:universal": "ng run my-app:build:production && ng run my-app:server:production",
      "server": "node dist-server/main.js",
      "test": "ng test",
      "test:ci": "cross-env CI=true ng test",
      "test:ssr": "run-p test:ssr:*",
      "test:ssr:server": "cross-env TEST=true node dist-server/main.js",
      "test:ssr:script": "node ./node_modules/npm-delay 2000 && ts-mocha test/*.spec.ts test/exit.ts --timeout 15000",
      "lint": "ng lint",
      "e2e": "ng e2e",
      "bundle-report": "ng build --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",
      "bundle-report:prod": "ng build --stats-json --prod && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",
      "dev:ssr": "ng run my-app:serve-ssr",
      "serve:ssr": "node dist-server/main.js",
      "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run my-app:server:production",
      "prerender": "ng run my-app:prerender",
      "postinstall": "ngcc",
      "wa": "webpack-bundle-analyzer --port 4300 dist/stats.json"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.0",
      "@angular/common": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/compiler": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/core": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/elements": "^10.1.0",
      "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
      "@angular/forms": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/localize": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/material": "^10.2.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/router": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/service-worker": "9.0.7",
      "@gorniv/ngx-universal": "^2.2.2",
      "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
      "@ng-select/ng-select": "^5.0.1",
      "@nguniversal/common": "9.0.2",
      "@nguniversal/express-engine": "9.0.2",
      "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
      "@ngx-meta/core": "8.0.2",
      "@ngx-translate/core": "12.1.2",
      "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",
      "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^9.0.0",
      "@types/facebook-js-sdk": "^3.3.0",
      "@types/loader-utils": "^2.0.1",
      "angular2-image-upload": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
      "bootstrap": "^4.4.0",
      "cookie-parser": "1.4.5",
      "dayjs": "^1.8.35",
      "express": "4.17.1",
      "firebase": "^7.19.1",
      "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
      "husky": "^4.2.5",
      "ng-gallery": "^5.0.0",
      "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
      "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.0.0",
      "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^1.1.3",
      "node-cache": "5.1.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
      "rxjs": "6.5.4",
      "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
      "speakingurl": "^14.0.1",
      "tslib": "1.11.1",
      "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@angular-devkit/architect": ">= 0.900 < 0.1100",
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.901.9",
      "@angular/cli": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/language-service": "9.0.7",
      "@angular/platform-server": "9.0.7",
      "@nguniversal/builders": "9.0.2",
      "@types/chai": "4.2.11",
      "@types/express": "4.17.3",
      "@types/jasmine": "3.5.9",
      "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
      "@types/node": "12.11.1",
      "@types/speakingurl": "^13.0.2",
      "chai": "4.2.0",
      "codelyzer": "5.2.1",
      "cross-env": "5.2.1",
      "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
      "firebase-functions": "^3.6.0",
      "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
      "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
      "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
      "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
      "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
      "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
      "karma": "^5.2.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
      "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
      "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
      "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.2",
      "mocha": "^8.1.3",
      "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
      "npm-delay": "1.0.4",
      "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
      "open": "^7.0.3",
      "prettier": "^1.19.1",
      "prettier-tslint": "^0.4.2",
      "protractor": "^7.0.0",
      "source-map-support": "0.5.16",
      "ssri": "6.0.1",
      "ts-mocha": "6.0.0",
      "ts-node": "8.8.0",
      "tslint": "5.20.1",
      "typescript": "3.7.5",
      "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.1",
      "webpack-cli": "3.3.11",
      "webpack-node-externals": "1.7.2"
    }
  }
```

I am suspecting that the Bootstrap loading method might not be right. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work. The problem was the percentage symbol of the css. So if you are changing opacity, do not use percentage symbol. instead decimals like %65 => 0.65